# Settings up SVN server with MySQL authentication

Tags: debian, apache-2.2, svn

The last few days I have been trying to set up my home SVN server using MySQL authentication. I believe I have all the applications installed, and hoped everything was configured right... but it still won't work.

I am running a Debian server, svn 1.5.1 and apache2.
This is my dav_svn.conf file:

```
<Location /svn>
  DAV svn
  SVNParentPath /var/svn-repos
  AuthBasicAuthoritative Off

  # our access control policy
  AuthzSVNAccessFile /var/svn-access/accessfile

  AuthMYSQL on
  AuthMySQL_Authoritative on
  AuthMySQL_DB svn
  AuthMySQL_Password_Table users
  AuthMySQL_Username_Field login
  AuthMySQL_Password_Field pass
  AuthMySQL_Empty_Passwords off
  AuthMySQL_Encryption_Types Crypt_MD5

  # try anonymous access first, resort to real
  # authentication if necessary.
  Satisfy Any
  Require valid-user

  AuthType Basic
  AuthName "Subversion repository"
  #AuthUserFile /var/www/svn-access/htpasswdsvnrepos
</Location>
```

I don't really know what I should put into my "accessfile" but maybe someone can explain that for me.

I get the following errors in my logs:

```
==> access.log <==
10.0.1.1 - - [25/Aug/2010:17:20:00 +0200] "GET /svn/project_wombat HTTP/1.1" 401 384 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; sv-SE; rv:1.9.2.8) Gecko/20100722 Firefox/3.6.8"

==> error.log <==
[Wed Aug 25 17:20:00 2010] [error] [client 10.0.1.1] Failed to load the AuthzSVNAccessFile: An authz rule refers to group '@project_wombat', which is undefined

==> access.log <==
10.0.1.1 - paulp [25/Aug/2010:17:20:03 +0200] "GET /svn/project_wombat HTTP/1.1" 401 384 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; sv-SE; rv:1.9.2.8) Gecko/20100722 Firefox/3.6.8"

==> error.log <==
[Wed Aug 25 17:20:03 2010] [error] Internal error: pcfg_openfile() called with NULL filename
[Wed Aug 25 17:20:03 2010] [error] [client 10.0.1.1] (9)Bad file descriptor: Could not open password file: (null)
```

On top of these issue I would like to define in a mysql db which users have access to which repositories.

This is my db setup:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `groups` (
  `gid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `name` varchar(50) NOT NULL default '',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`gid`),
  UNIQUE KEY `name` (`name`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=3 ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `usergroup` (
  `uid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
  `gid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`uid`,`gid`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
  `uid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `login` varchar(20) NOT NULL default '',
  `pass` varchar(60) NOT NULL default '',
  `firstname` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
  `lastname` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
  `email` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`uid`),
  UNIQUE KEY `login` (`login`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=2 ;
```

Anyone who can help me, maybe put me in the right direction?

Regards,
Paul Peelen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it working, for now.

I still don't got the project grouping working, but thats a problem for later.

I used the drupal user table layout (don't ask me why! ;) )
And this is my dav_svn.conf:

```
<Location /svn>
    DAV svn
    SVNParentPath /var/svn-repos
    Order Deny,Allow
    Allow from All

    # basic settings
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "Stare SVN Server"
    Auth_MySQL On
    Auth_MySQL_Authoritative On

    # work-around for "Bad file descriptor"
    AuthUserFile /dev/null
    AuthBasicAuthoritative Off

    #MySQL DB
    Auth_MySQL_Host localhost
    Auth_MySQL_DB "svn"
    Auth_MySQL_User "root"
    Auth_MySQL_Password "password"

    #User Tables
    Auth_MySQL_Password_Table "users"
    Auth_MySQL_Username_Field "name"
    Auth_MySQL_Password_Field "pass"
    Auth_MySQL_Encryption_Types PHP_MD5
    Auth_MySQL_Empty_Passwords off

    #Group Tables
    Auth_MySQL_Group_Table "users, users_roles"
    Auth_MySQL_Group_Field users_roles.rid

    #WHERE Clauses
    Auth_MySQL_Password_Clause " AND status = 1"
    Auth_MySQL_Group_Clause " AND users_roles.uid = users.uid"

    #read access
    <Limit GET PROPFIND OPTIONS REPORT>
        Require valid-user
    </Limit>

    #write access
    <LimitExcept GET PROPFIND OPTIONS REPORT>
        # change this to the rid of the role you allow to commit
        Require group 4
    </LimitExcept>

</Location>
```

/P